# How to make custom scoring metric for cross_validate in scikit learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to develop pr_auc as the scoring metric for cross_validate(). So I followed Scikit Learn's user guide: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring

My code is shown below:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import auc, make_scorer

def cus_pr_auc(x, y):
    score=auc(x, y)
    return score

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=2, n_redundant=0,
    n_clusters_per_class=2, weights=[0.9], flip_y=0, random_state=7)

model = XGBClassifier(scale_pos_weight=9)

scores = cross_validate(model, X, y, scoring=make_scorer(cus_pr_auc, greater_is_better=True), cv=3, n_jobs=-1)
```

However, I got the following error message:

> ValueError: x is neither increasing nor decreasing : [1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
>    0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>    1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1
>    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
>    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
>    1].

How do I fix the code?

Comment: auc seems a weird choice here. Why don't you use something like f1_score?

Comment: Precision-Recall AUC is a good test for algorithm's performance focused in the rare events. The area under the Precision-Recall Curve is a good approximation of the algorithm's skill for rare event classification.

Answer (score 0):

Change your metric from `auc` to `roc_auc_score` as below and you're fine to go:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score, make_scorer

def cus_pr_auc(x, y):
    score=roc_auc_score(x, y)
    return score

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=2, n_redundant=0,
    n_clusters_per_class=2, weights=[0.9], flip_y=0, random_state=7)

model = XGBClassifier(scale_pos_weight=9)

scores = cross_validate(model, X, y, scoring=make_scorer(cus_pr_auc, greater_is_better=True), cv=3, n_jobs=-1)

scores
{'fit_time': array([0.0627017, 0.0569284, 0.046772 ]),
 'score_time': array([0.00534487, 0.00616908, 0.00347471]),
 'test_score': array([0.90244639, 0.90242424, 0.94969697])}
```

Your `auc` is not working because, according to [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.auc.html):

> x coordinates. These must be either monotonic increasing or monotonic decreasing.

Hence your error (see [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/496e7106fa8fff9e955620ec8b3b74d1bba59453/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py#L92) as well, for concrete source of your error message).

Generally `auc` is a low level scoring metric which is used as `auc(fpr,tpr)`.

Comment: The use of roc_auc_score() is for balanced dataset. For imbalanced dataset, roc auc is not a good measurement of algorithm performance.

Comment: @David293836 You need to check the docs for definitions of what is `auc` and `roc_auc_score`. Plus, your comments are contradicting each other.

Comment: I have figured out the reason why my code does not work. The reason is that the custom make_scorer() function's first argument needs to have the input of (y_actual, and y_predict). So custom auc function does not work because it takes the input of (x, y). Can you explain why my comments are contracting?

Comment: `auc` is used for strictly increasing or decreasing data, like `auc(fpr,tpr)`. You need to use `roc_auc_score` towards your goals.

Comment: >>> `So custom auc function does not work because it takes the input of (x, y)`. It's not true. See your error message why it's not working.

Comment: There are a few points here: (1) roc_auc_score is not a good measurement for imbalanced dataset, (2) if one wants to use roc_auc_score, make_scorer() is not needed because roc_auc_score is a prefined metric already, (3) I agree that auc needs to take input like (fpr, tpr) with fpt is strickly increasing or decreasing. However, make_scorer does not support such operation. See section 3.3.1.3 of this link: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter